# Print Arabic text in Vala

Tags: c, unicode, locale, glib, vala

I tried

```
print ("السلام عليكم\n");
```

it outputs

```
?????? ?????
```

After looking at the generated c code

```
...
g_print ("السلام عليكم\n");
...
```

it appears that they're using g_print() which it is not doing that same as printf() in C which works perfectly fine with Arabic.

So, is there anyway to print arabic text in Vala?

Comment: [printing utf8 in glib](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3092354/1606345)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this to the start of your code:

```
Intl.setlocale (LocaleCategory.ALL, "");
```

By leaving the second parameter an empty string you're loading the LOCALE that the current user has set (which is likely to be a UTF-8 based one on modern Linux systems).

Windows is a different story here ...

See also:

- https://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.Intl.setlocale.html
- [printing utf8 in glib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3092354/1606345)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_localization_functions
- http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale

Comment: Or from Vala 0.28 you can use `Intl.setlocale ();` because `LocaleCategory.ALL, ""` are now the default arguments.